# Introduction to dynamic loading in C++

Tags: c++

Currently I am developing embedded application which needs to use as low CPU as possible. The main loop is writing some bits to output. Number of loop iterations is very important variable, let's call it `N`.

`N` can be in range of 0 to 3.

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    WriteBits();
}
```

This approach uses `N` variable saved in config file, which is loaded during application start. This approach is very comfortable, setting `N` value needs only to replace value stored in configuration file.

But another way to code it, is to involve define macros:

```
#define N 3
...
WriteBits();
#if N >= 1
WriteBits();
#endif

#if N >= 2
WriteBits();
#endif

#if N == 3
WriteBits();
#endif
```

This method is much faster, but of course needs `N` value to be hardcoded.

Is there another approach which would let `N` variable to be loaded from file while running and insert it into `#if` statements?

My application is running on Linux Raspbian.

EDIT:

This application is used to display text on LED panels. When I use for loop method, framerate is about 145 Hz. When using defines it's getting to 200 Hz.

Comment: preprocessor macros are evaluated compile time so it won't be possible.

Comment: Not really. `ifdefs` and `constexpr` are compile time mechanisms which need to be evaluated at compile time. A value read from a file is runtime dependend so you need runtime mechanisms (like for). But you could measure the best performance with the file and then later hard-code the best value for you.

Comment: Depending on the structure surrounding this, you could have four methods `WriteNoBits()`, `WriteOneBits()`, `WriteTwoBits()`, `WriteThreeBits()`, and call via a function pointer dependent on `N`.  The only other idea I can think of (which is quite extreme) is dynamic code-generation, which is very platform-dependent.  Are you confident that the overhead here is actually significant compared to the I/O that's (presumably) occurring?

Comment: "This method is much faster" how much is much?

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth:
It is very simple. My app is displaying text on LED panels. When I use for loop I got 145 Hz, when I use defines framerate is getting to 200 Hz. Maybe there is another way to keep comfortable value loading and framerate high?

Comment: Well, I definitely question the need to update text at 200Hz, but I'm glad that you've measured it :)  That said, I still find it hard to believe that the loop conditional is that significant compared to the (presumably) 10s or 100s of cycles need to push out an update to the display.

Comment: BTW the term "dynamic loading" already means something, it is not appropriate here.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, I did not have any clue how to call this thread.

Comment: If this loop is a part of another tight loop, you can try to specialize the other loop for different values of N.

Comment: I suggest "Optimizing a for loop", because that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well more getting rid of the for loop in a runtime dynamic way.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth could you post your comment as answer? Yours method gave me 170 Hz which is good enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*[To kick off, I definitely question the need to refresh a text display at 200Hz!  I'm also curious as to why the loop conditional has so much impact, given that `WriteBits` is presumably spending 10s or 100s of cycles actually doing the update.]*</sup>

---

One alternative approach is to have four individual functions, `writeZeroBits()`, `writeOneBits()`, etc. and call via a function pointer depending on the value of `N`.  Assuming `N` changes relatively infrequently, then this avoids the conditional, but is still fully "dynamic" (at the expense of having to maintain four functions instead of one).

Comment: This method gave me advance from 145 Hz to 170 Hz which is good optimization. I need as much frames per second as possible, because next thing is to create a lot of LED panels connected to RPi. I will try further steps using asembler. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use simple switch without break:

```
switch(N){
    case 3: WriteBits(); //no break
    case 2: WriteBits(); //no break
    case 1: WriteBits(); //no break
    //case 0: WriteBits(); // If you need N+1 call
}
```

Comment: Any compiler worth its salt will know when to do this for you. But even if your compiler is worth its salt, this will _seriously_ throw the optimizer off track.

Comment: This wouldn't behave correctly. You would get 1 call extra for any N.

Comment: @michalsrb it depends on which behaviour user needs. Because two examples in question are controversial. I'll edit this in

Comment: You can always check here what assembler code the compiler generates. http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: @teivaz You are right, the two examples are conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, as long as COUNT is a literal.

```
#define LOOP(COUNT, X) LOOP_##COUNT(X)
#define LOOP_1(X) X;
#define LOOP_2(X) LOOP_1(X) LOOP_1(X)
#define LOOP_3(X) LOOP_2(X) LOOP_1(X)
#define LOOP_4(X) LOOP_2(X) LOOP_2(X)
#define LOOP_5(X) LOOP_3(X) LOOP_2(X)
#define LOOP_6(X) LOOP_3(X) LOOP_3(X)
#define LOOP_7(X) LOOP_4(X) LOOP_3(X)
#define LOOP_8(X) LOOP_4(X) LOOP_4(X)
#define LOOP_9(X) LOOP_5(X) LOOP_4(X)
#define LOOP_10(X) LOOP_5(X) LOOP_5(X)
```

Comment: he reads "count" from a file during runtime (as stated in the question)

Comment: There's no way to have a dynamically-sized unrolled loop. "count" can be `#include`-d, but the compiler can't unroll a loop if it doesn't know how many iterations there are at compile time.

Comment: Yes. That is what most people in the comments said.

Answer (score 0):

If your timing has to be so precise, you can not rely on your C compiler to generate you optimal code. You'll need to write assembler yourself.

I would suggest structure like this:

```
  jump to (start + (3-N)*<length of code of WriteBits>)
start:
  <code of WriteBits>
  <code of WriteBits>
  <code of WriteBits>
  end
```

Comment: would some C gotos do the same?

Comment: goto can jump only to specific label, not to a calculated address

Comment: Actually compilers have gotten pretty good at inlining functions & unrolling loops

Comment: well we probably need to measure stuff to know for certain.

Comment: @StoryTeller True. There is a hope that compiler would generate something like this it if it somehow got the information that N will never be bigger than 3. But I still thing that if the timing is that critical that every instruction matter, it's not good to rely on compiler. It can do something else every time.

Comment: At least with GCC you can do something like this: `void *labels[] = { &&label1, &&label2, &&label3 }; goto *labels[N];`.